# Why does i print the same value as the number I want less than?

Tags: c++

Consider

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int i = 0;    
    while (i < 10)
    i++;
    std::cout << i << endl;
}
```

I just wanted to know, why does this print out 10? if it is i < 10, shouldn't it be 9 that is printed? I appreciate any help

Comment: What happens when `i==9`?

Comment: You may want to add some indentation or `{ }` to your code to clarify what happens when `i < 10` is **true** and what happens when `i < 10` is **false**.

Answer (score 2):

Because when `i` is 9, `(i < 10)` is `true`, so the `while` body runs, which increments `i` by 1 thereby setting it to 10. Sure, on that last iteration of the `while` body, `i++` is an *expression* equal to 9, but with the side-effect of increasing `i`.

Comment: Just to clarify, since the program still sees that 9 is less than 10, it continues to increment i until it can finally read that 10 is no longer less than 10. As a result, it prints 10.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what happens inside the loop,

> do this as long as `i` is less than 10

is the same as

> do this until `i` is greater than or equal to 10

So the value of `i` *after* the loop must be (at least) 10, since that's when it stops.

Answer (score 0):

Because the i in `while(i < 10)` stays in the loop til i is equals to 10, i compares the values with 10 so when it reaches 10 it will break out of the loop and it would print it out